# Named adapters with grok and Plone?

Tags: plone, zope, grok

Is it possible to register named adapters with five.grok.

The ZCML equivalent would be:

```
    <adapter name="description" factory=".indexers.mytype_description" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grok equivalent is

```
from five import grok
grok.global_adapter(mytype_description, name='description')
```